# Date String in Datetime Format Python

Tags: python, datetime

Here is my error I do not manage to solve

```
ValueError: time data '1/31/2021 22:59' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

Here is my code
90% of the time my String date I need to convert goes in my `try` part and It works, I have a problem with my second part.

```
def StringToDateTime(DateString):
    from datetime import datetime
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(DateString, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    except:
        DateString = str(DateString)+':00'
        return datetime.strptime(DateString, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: you want `'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'` - month obviously comes first in your string and it has no second

Comment: Omg of course thanks a lot I was tired :)

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is due to the `str` not having a seconds value -- the `%S` of the datetime format string.

Change the format string so it doesn't have the seconds placeholder, and it should work as expected:

```py
try:
    # Remove the %S from the format string here
    return datetime.strptime(DateString, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

except:
    DateString = str(DateString)+':00'
    return datetime.strptime(DateString, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Or, if you want to alter the `DateString` as you do in your `except` clause:

```py
# Add the seconds to the date string
DateString = f"{DateString}:00"

try:
    return datetime.strptime(DateString, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
except:
    return datetime.strptime(DateString, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```